# Applying CSS class to all rows but not the table heading

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to apply a css style to change color of clicked rows of an HTML table. On the click event, I am adding the class (selected-row). Now, my table has a sorting functionality when clicking on the heading of each column. The heading gets colored which is not what I want. I want only rows but not the heading. So, I changed my style to (not first child). Now, the heading AND first row don't get color changed. I need only the heading to NOT change color and all other rows to change color when I add selected-row class.

```
.selected-row:not(:first-child) {
    background-color: brown;
    color: #FFF;
}

            $("#example tr").click(function () {
                $(this).addClass('selected-row').siblings().removeClass('selected-row');


            });
```

Answer (score 2):

If you mark up your table with a `<thead>` to contain the header row, and `<tbody>` to contain the data rows, you can specifically target *only rows in the table body* - like this in CSS:

```
tbody > tr { }
```

And like this in jQuery:

```
$('#example tbody > tr')...
```

Table mark-up:

```
<table>
    <caption>This table contains...</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Heading</th>
            <th>Heading</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td>Total</td>
            <td>$50</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Item 1</td>
            <td>$20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Item 2</td>
            <td>$30</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to potentially do it would be to wrap your table header in `<thead></thead>` and body in `<tbody></tbody>` and then apply whatever selector as

```
$("#example tbody tr").click(function () {...});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`th`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/th) for the header row element.

Answer (score 0):

You can target "td" tags:

```
$("#example tr td").click(function () {
                $(this).parent().addClass('selectedrow').siblings().removeClass('selected-row');
```

If you are using "th" tags in your table:

```
<table style="width:100%">
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th> 
        <th>Age</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td> 
        <td>50</td>
      </tr>
   </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to modify your header using the `th` or `tbody` tags, you could do something like this.

```
$("table tr:gt(0)").click(function(){
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('selected-row');
    $(this).addClass('selected-row');
})
```

You can see this working in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/garrettascott/dna1r962/)